# CLI tool to run commands defined in a config file

Tags: shell-script, command-line, make, productivity

I'm working as part of a team of developers on a software project with many moving parts. We use a Makefile to easily run commands and scripts that are regularly needed during development. Examples might be:

- Set up a Python virtualenv.
- Intialize the local development database.
- Run a linter.
- etc.

Most of these commands don't need to be customizable using additional arguments, so Makefile targets work perfectly:

```
.PHONY: venv
venv:
    python3 -m venv venv
    venv/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt
```

```bsh
$ make venv
```

But it gets really cumbersome if additional arguments need to be passed to a command from time to time. Two straight-forwared ways are:

- Pass the aditional arguments via a variable, e.g. `make foo FOO_ARGS="lalala"`. Cumbersome and messy if arguments contain spaces.
- Find the target in the Makefile, copy it to the shell prompt and edit it.

#### Idea for a solution

I came up with a really simple concept of what I actually need: A command line tool, e.g. called `run`, that looks for an executable file called `runfile` in the current directory and its parents and executes that file, passing any command line arguments to that file. Implemented in Python it could look like this:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import sys, os, subprocess, pathlib

cwd = pathlib.Path().resolve()

# Go through the CWD (current working directory) and all its parents and look
# for an executable file called "runfile".
for dir in [cwd, *cwd.parents]:
    run_script_path = dir / 'runfile'

    if os.access(run_script_path, os.X_OK):
        break
else:
    print(
        f'No executable runfile found in {cwd} or any of its parents.',
        file=sys.stderr)

    sys.exit(1)

# Run the runfile, forwarding any command line arguments to it. Use the parent
# of the runfile as CWD and pass the original CWD in the environment variable
# "RUN_PWD".
subprocess.run(
    [run_script_path, *sys.argv[1:]],
    cwd=dir,
    env=dict(os.environ, RUN_PWD=str(cwd)))
```

The runfile could be using any scripting language. I could e.g. be a Bash script:

```bsh
#! /usr/bin/env bash

case "$1" in
    venv)
        rm -rf venv
        echo python3 -m venv "${@:2}" venv
        ;;
    lint)
        pycodestyle --exclude='./venv,./node_modules,./.git' "${@:2}" .
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Unknown command: $1" >&2
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

(`"${@:2}"` inserts the script's arguments following the first one as separate words into a command line).

```bsh
$ run venv --copies
# Would run "python3 -m venv --copies venv".
```

#### The question

Is there already a tool like this that maybe has more features? It would be ok if the tool used its own language to define commands instead of simply executing the file.

#### Additional notes

I know that some build also have support for this as secondary features, e.g. `npm` allows defining [`scripts`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/scripts) that can be invoked from the command line:

```bsh
npm run foo -- args...
```

But this already requires two words before the name of the script and a `--` before additional arguments, not as convenient as it could be.

Installing [console scripts entry points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html#console-scripts) into a virtualenv and activating the virtualenv may sometimes be a solution. But in this case one of the use-cases is to set up the project's virtualenv, so that's a chicken-egg-problem.

I know that I could probably hack `$(MAKECMDGOALS)`. No.

Comment: Doesn't `ansible` come close?

Comment: Read `man run-parts`.

Comment: @Bib How so? How can I pass additional arguments in a more convenient way than with `make` or `npm`?

Comment: @waltinator `run-parts -a venv -a --copies` is not really better than `npm run venv -- --copies`, especially if the list of arguments gets longer or shell globbing is used. Also, we have multiple executable files in the project's root.